# Does "gcloud docker" support some kind of sudo (e.g., --user root?)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a setup where docker ONLY works as root (I know, my fault). I'm trying to follow the GCR quickstart: [1]. I can't find anything on the troubleshooting page [2] either.

Can you help me (and I can then file a document fix)?

[1] https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/quickstart
[2] https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support/troubleshooting

## Repro

Reproduction steps (also in b/68796816):

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2
ricc@rubino:~/git/gce-recipes/gke/quickstart-image$ sudo docker run busybox date
Thu Nov  2 12:29:35 UTC 2017
$ sudo docker tag quickstart-image gcr.io/ric-cccwiki/quickstart-image 
# All good so far ...
```

Option 1 (no sudo):

```
# no sudo: docker doesn't work
$ gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/ric-cccwiki/quickstart-image
FATA[0000] Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/images/gcr.io/ric-cccwiki/quickstart-image/push?tag=: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
```

Option 2: with sudo:

```
# docker works but gcloud is not found
$ sudo gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/ric-cccwiki/quickstart-image
sudo: gcloud: command not found
```

Neither way works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options, the best being to just make docker usable without root: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/

**Option 1: Specify your full path to gcloud when using it.**

```
sudo $(which gcloud)
```

**Option 2: Install glcoud as root**

```
sudo su
#install gcloud
gcloud version
```

However, the best thing to do is to just use docker as non-root :)

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed the docker as root - was a no brainer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Jake suggests: `gcloud docker` is on the deprecation path, for this reason among others.

I'd recommend doing `gcloud components install docker-credential-gcr` 
followed by `which docker-credential-gcr`, `cp`ing the binary to a location 
on root's PATH.

`sudo docker-credential-gcr configure-docker` followed by 
`sudo docker-credential-gcr gcr-login` should then allow you to use `sudo 
docker` without issue.

See credentials helper's docs:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/docker-credential-gcr